# Lua template processor question

Tags: templates, lua

I'm going to use that template engine [LTP](http://www.savarese.com/software/ltp/) . There is not so much doc available.

Now i'm stuck how to pass an environment into the render engine. I have basically this:

```
local ltp = require("ltp.template")
ltp.render(io.stdout, 1, "index.dhtm", false, {}, "<?lua", "?>", { total="2400" })
```

What data structure should be the last parameter (env_code), a string, a table with key=val ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an array of string. each string should be in key=value form.